# Не могу импортировать установленный мной модуль Python

Tags: python, импорт, модули, установка

Мне нужна была библиотека PyAudio. В командную строку зашёл, установил. Захожу в программу, пишу `import PyAudio` и...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PyAudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyAudio'
```

да.

Почему я не могу импортировать модуль?
Уже пробовал перезаходить в редактор кода и перезагружать компьютер.

Comment: маленькие буквы должны быть - ``import pyaudio``

Comment: `Camel case` - для классов. Переменные и подключаемые модули называются маленькими буквами.

Comment: Все равно не работает.

Comment: значит, не установил. Что было написано в процессе установки?

Comment: Не помню. Не копировал.

Comment: Переустановил. Вот сообщение:
`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`

`Collecting pyaudio`

 `Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)`

`Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (164 kB)`

`installing collected packages: pyaudio`

`Successfully installed pyaudio-0.2.14`
Но всё равно модуль не импортируется.

Comment: Что пишет pip freeze? Как запускаешь код?

Comment: 1. Я пишу import pyaudio, и снова вылезает та же ошибка, что и в вопросе. 2. Писать просто pip freeze или pip freeze pyaudio?

Comment: В какой среде пишешь код? PyCharm ?

Comment: Я пишу в Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0):

Если стоят две или больше версий питона - попробуй их снести, и поставить питон заново. Не раз сталкивался, когда библиотека ставится в один питон, а запускается другой.

Answer (score 0):

При установке библиотек, лучше это делать локально для проекта. Создать виртуальное окружение, установить нужные библиотеки и работать с кодом внутри. Тогда не будет ошибок с установкой библиотек внутрь других версий питона. Даже если установлено множество версий питона.

Comment: Нет, библиотеки устанавливаются, ошибок нет. Ошибка вылезает, когда я пишу `import module_name` (если что, я работаю в Sublime Text 3).

Comment: Внутри самого голого python запускается импорт библиотеки?
Для всех модулей такая ошибка или только для pyaudio?

Comment: Bitegus, для всех

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть где располагаются стандартные библиотеки внутри интерпретатора Python для этого из вашей среды запустите:
import math
print(math.__file__) 

Поскольку модуль math встроен в питон, он должен показать путь для стандартной библиотеки. Далее в папке .../lib/python3.х или в папке ...lib/site-packages ищите требуемый модуль, если его там нет, то перенесите его туда физически или задайте стандартной папкой установки через интерпретатор